# Powerbuilder 8 code

Tags: powerbuilder

We have an application built in PowerBuilder 8. I have ZERO experience with PowerBuilder 8 and limited programming experience in general. One of the functions of the application is to take a filename (.txt) that you enter, look for it in a directory and then process that file adding it to our SQL database. I found a job in SQL which is what I believe is being executed by the PowerBuilder program but I am having a tough time navigating PowerBuilder to find the code that confirms that.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: This is a pretty board question, I'd suggest narrowing it and making it less subjective. In regards to your question, I'd rewrite the project in something that isn't PowerBuilder if it was me haha.

Comment: Internet searches will be your best best (Powerbuild forums maybe?).  SO's raison d'etre is to solve your programming problems when your code doesn't work, not to teach you about new languages, systems, etc.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps I can share. You say you have a PB app. To search thru the app, you need the .PBL files. If you only have PBD's much more difficult and requires additional software.

I am going to assume you have the actual PB 8 Powerbuilder software. The. Workspace and target are defined and you can see a library list. Look for systree on the toolbar

Since you are new, this may seem like a lot of information but you would need this to be able to search the application.

If PBL's are available and other defined as mentioned above search on IFEXISTS. That may help you determine if the functionality is there.

Have a good day and best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

From the 'File' menu choose 'Open Workspace' - then navigate to the folder where your code is.  PB will filter out other stuff and only show you Workspace items (file extension of 'PBW').

Open the workspace.

Locate the library painter in the IDE of PowerBuilder - it should appear as a treeview control.  Click on the treeview node of the above Workspace.  There should be at least one 'Target' node below the workspace.

Right click on the Target and choose 'Search'.  Search for ".txt".  This will show all the places in your application where the string ".txt" is used.  This should at least get you to the place where the code you seek is - assuming like in your OP the files have the extension of ".txt".